# Rails ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch for user id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 5.2.6 app with a PostgresQL db.  Its purpose is to consume an API for cocktails, displaying cocktails that match a query.  Each cocktail in the response has an "Add Favorite" button to save that particular cocktail into the local database.  This would allow a list of favorites for each user that is local.

Users is set up with Devise gem.
There are 2 Classes, Pages and Cocktails.  Cocktails has full CRUD and can add drinks without using the API.  The CRUD for the Cocktails class is fully tested and works.  It successfully creates new cocktails without using the api.

Where I'm at now is consuming the API with a query, displaying the response in a list, and giving the user an "Add Favorite" button next to each entry to add a specific new drink to their favorites list that is tied to their user profile.

But I'm having trouble because I've never tried to create without a erb form.

After much research, I think I found the code to do it.  However, I'm getting an error when I pass the params after hitting the "Add Favorite" button.  The error is:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in CocktailsController#create
User(#70044407074280) expected, got "6" which is an instance of String(#47022904663520)
```

"6" is actually the user id of the user I'm logged in as.  But I think its not the same type?

Here is the view

```
<h1>Search for Cocktails</h1>

   <%= form_tag(search_results_page_path, method: :get) do %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:search, params[:search]) %>
      <%= button_tag "Search", :class => 'btn', :name => nil %>
    <% end %> 
  

  <% if @drinks.any? %>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Alcohol</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Glass</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
        <% @drinks["drinks"].each do |drink| %>
          <tr>
            <th rowspan="3" scope="rowgroup"><%= image_tag drink["strDrinkThumb"], :class => 'drink-thumb' %></th>
            <td><%= drink["strDrink"] %></td>
            <td><%= drink["strAlcoholic"] %></td>
            <td><%= drink["strCategory"] %></td>
            <td><%= drink["strGlass"] %></td>
            <td><%= button_to "Add Favorite", { :controller => "cocktails", :action => "create", :cocktail => {:name => drink["strDrink"], :category => drink["strCategory"], :alcoholic => drink["strAlcoholic"], :glass => drink["strGlass"], :instructions => drink["strInstructions"], :ingredients => drink["strIngredient1"], :api_id_drink => drink["idDrink"], :api_image_url => drink["strDrinkThumb"], :user => current_user }}, {:method => :post} %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4" scope="colgroup" ><%= drink["strInstructions"] %> </td>
          </tr>
          <% i = 1 %>
          <% while !drink["strIngredient" + i.to_s].nil? do %>
            <tr>
              <% if i > 1 %>
                <td></td>
              <% end %>
              <td><%= drink["strIngredient" + i.to_s] %> </td>
              <td><%= drink["strMeasure" + i.to_s] %> </td>
            </tr>
            <% i = i + 1 %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  <% end %>

<br>
<%= link_to 'Back to Favorites', root_path %>
```

Here's the cocktails controller

```
require 'drinks'

class CocktailsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_cocktail, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /cocktails or /cocktails.json
  def index
    @cocktails = current_user.cocktails
    render :index
  end

  # GET /cocktails/1 or /cocktails/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /cocktails/new
  def new
    @cocktail = Cocktail.new
    render :new 
  end

  # GET /cocktails/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /cocktails or /cocktails.json
  def create
    @cocktail = current_user.cocktails.build(cocktail_params)
    if @cocktail.save
      redirect_to @cocktail, notice:'Cocktail was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /cocktails/1 or /cocktails/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cocktail.update(cocktail_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cocktail, notice: "Cocktail was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cocktail }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @cocktail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /cocktails/1 or /cocktails/1.json
  def destroy
    @cocktail.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cocktails_url, notice: "Cocktail was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cocktail
      @cocktail = Cocktail.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def cocktail_params
      params.require(:cocktail).permit(:name, :category, :alcoholic, :glass, :instructions, :ingredients, :user)
    end
end
```

This is the Pages Controller, it was meant to handle the search and the api call, it has no model (its is accessing the api call drinks.rb which is in /services using httparty)

```
require 'drinks'

class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def search
    render :search
  end

  def search_results
    @search = params[:search]
    api_call = Drink.new(@search.strip)
    response = api_call.drink_name
    api_error_handler(response)
    render :search_results
  end
  
  private
  
  def api_error_handler(response)
    @drinks = JSON(response.body)
    if @drinks["drinks"].blank?
      flash[:alert] = "We couldn't find that cocktail"
      return @drinks = {}
    end

    case response.code
    when 200
      flash[:alert] = "Search Complete"
    when 404
      flash[:alert] = "Sorry, That cocktail wasn't found."
      @drinks = {}
    when 400..403
      flash[:alert] = "Error #{response.code}"
      @drinks = {}
    when 405..499
      flash[:alert] = "Error #{response.code}"
      @drinks = {}
    when 500..600
      flash[:alert] = "Server Error #{response.code}.  Please try again a little later."
      @drinks = {}
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Unknown Error"
      @drinks = {}
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the Cocktail model:

```
require 'httparty'

class Cocktail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :category, presence: true
  validates :alcoholic, presence: true
  validates :instructions, presence: true
  validates :ingredients, presence: true
  validates_length_of :instructions, maximum: 500
  validates_length_of :ingredients, maximum: 300

  def self.api_call
    @drinks = HTTParty.get('http://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita')

  end

end
```

In the error message I get, these are the listed params:

```
 Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/cocktails_controller.rb:29:in `create'

Request

Parameters:

{"authenticity_token"=>"DQPbxSRMcJgL+xX5JDzL6arDG/yQ7s5J+eBTmwtpnbKCV7SMbJI7EJ/9UoH55z8o+lL8XQsTUUICHAgtlzVwkQ==",
 "cocktail"=>
  {"alcoholic"=>"Alcoholic",
   "api_id_drink"=>"17141",
   "api_image_url"=>"https://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/rx8k8e1504365812.jpg",
   "category"=>"Punch / Party Drink",
   "glass"=>"Beer mug",
   "ingredients"=>"Red wine",
   "instructions"=>"Throw it all together and serve real cold.",
   "name"=>"Smut",
   "user"=>"6"}}
```

So it like its mostly working to create the new cocktail, just a problem with the :user param.  I tried using each of the following in the button params:

```
:user => session[:user_id]
:user => current_user
:user => current_user.id
```

I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass the user in from the view.  I'd suggest removing the 'user' param from both the view and `cocktail_params`.

Comment: That was it!  You got it vinyl, it immediately created it and added it.  Thank you, you saved me from a headache!

Comment: Great! I moved my comment to an answer for more visibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Devise, `current_user` is accessible from your controllers.  So, there's no need to try and pass in a user object or id as a param from the view.  Removing `user` as a param will fix the error.